# How To Retrieve First PAR Node from Content Page

Tags: java, iteration, aem

I am iterating through all child pages to display their titles and links. But I also need to display the first paragraph node, if it exists.

For example, wow would I retrieve the first PAR node from the following content page?

```
/content
  /foo
     /jcr:content
        /title
        /par <- need this one
        /par
        /image
```

I thought [Page class](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/javadoc/com/day/cq/wcm/api/Page.html) `getProperties().get()` method would work, but I only see examples returning attributes within jcr:content, not any child nodes below it.

```
    ArrayList aChildren = new ArrayList();
    String listroot = properties.get("listRoot", currentPage.getPath());

    Page rootPage = pageManager.getPage(listroot);
    if (rootPage != null) {
        Iterator<Page> children = rootPage.listChildren(new PageFilter(request));

        while (children.hasNext()) {
            Page child = children.next();

            out.println( child.getTitle() + "<br>" );
            //Output first PAR tag of this page here
        }

    }
```

Can this be done with  or another CQ-specific tag, or is this a job for java functions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You would have to iterate through the child nodes of the child page.

Get the first node with resource type parsys. Once you have that node you can get its path and include it on the current page.

```
Resource childResource = resourceResolver.getResource(child.getPath());
Node childNode = childResource.adaptTo(Node.class);
Node jcrContent = childNode.getNode("jcr:content");
NodeIterator childrenNodes = jcrContent.getNodes();

while(childrenNodes.hasNext()){
    Node next = childrenNodes.nextNode();
    String resourceType = next.getProperty("sling:resourceType").getString();
    if(resourceType.equals("foundation/components/parsys")){
        %><cq:include path="<%= next.getPath() %>" resourceType="foundation/components/parsys" /><%
        break;
    }
}
```

This will embed on the current page the first parsys component on the child pages. I have not tested this, so there may be some modifications that need to be made to make it work.

Comment: Type mismatch: cannot convert from Property to String ( for `String resourceType = next.getProprty("sling:resourceType")`

Comment: This is off-topic, but would I be able to retrieve the paragraph content without using `cq:include`? I need to pass the contents to a variable.

Comment: `next.getProperty("sling:resourceType").getString()` You could pass the par node var around and as needed access the content contained in the under the par.

Comment: This returns the type of component page being used for this content page. (-site-/components/page/popuppage)

Comment: Do we need to have another inner loop to traverse anything below the current `jcr:content` node?

Comment: `childeNode` is the `Node` type of `child` of `Page` type. My example is missing getting the `jcr:content` node. You would do the iterations on that node, where the parsys nodes would be. I will fix my code example.

Comment: Pretty much all of this functionality I'm learning on the go, so I have little ability to fill in the blanks like this. Your persistence is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You could also try with this:

```
<%@page session="false" import="com.day.cq.wcm.foundation.Paragraph,
                                com.day.cq.wcm.foundation.ParagraphSystem"%>
<%
ParagraphSystem parSys = ParagraphSystem.create(resource, slingRequest);
for (Paragraph par: parSys.paragraphs()){
```

With this you can iterate through the parsys nodes that are under current resource.

Comment: How do I iterate further into this result for child nodes?: `Paragraph, path=/content/-site-/test/news/news3/jcr:content, type=-site-/components/page/popuppage, cssClass=default, column=0/0, diffInfo=[null], resource=[JcrNodeResource, type=-site-/components/page/popuppage, superType=null, path=/content/-site-/test/news/news3/jcr:content]`

Comment: Just use the adaptTo(Node.class) on each result, and you can call the  getNodes() method on that object, so you can use the NodeIterator to go through the child nodes of the parsys.

Answer (score 1):

Every node in CQ5 repository can be represented as a [Resource](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/javadoc/org/apache/sling/api/resource/Resource.html). You can get the resource by using following code

```
//resolver being instance of org.apache.sling.api.resource.ResourceResolver
Resource paraResource = resolver.getResource("path of the paragraph");
```

Then you can manipulate on the resource

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to reference the parsys from one page to another, I would use the out of the box [reference component](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/wcm/default_components.html#Reference).  This component accepts a path to a component any where on your site, and displays it on the page of your choice.

Comment: The pages that will be called are entered by the user, so the reference component isn't flexible enough. Also, if a PAR doesn't exist for a given page then nothing should be returned; reference would be useless in this regard since the system, and not the user needs to perform the tree search.